# Why Is MongoDB So Fast

Tags: mongodb

I was showing my co-worker performance benchmarks of MongoDB vs SQL Server 2008 and while he believes MongoDB is faster, he doesn't understand how it's possible. His logic, was that SQL has been around for decades, and has some of the smartest people working on it, and how can MongoDB - a relatively new kid on the block be so superior in performance? I wasn't able to really provide a solid and technical answer, and I was hoping you guys could assist.

Comment: You gotta make sure to compare apples with apples, and not two totally different things...

Comment: @marc_s Well I think MongoDB and SQL are apple with apple, in terms of  data storage.

Comment: @Jack That's like saying it's fair to compare a motorcycle and a tank because they're both vehicles.

Comment: I love looking at the performance sheets from some of these “web”/“cloud” scale offerings.  They turn off all the relatability and run everything in memory then crank the relational stores they are working against to the highest consistency and reliability possible.   Yes, storing object is RAM is really, really fast but it also is extremely expensive and volatile.   We also ignore that is make data duplication a requirement as soon as you want to reverse the lookup and get any sort of performance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

MongoDB isn't like a traditional relational database. It's [noSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) or document based, it provides weak consistency guarantees, and it doesn't have to guarantee consistency like SQL.

Comment: ok, So why not create a non robust relational database that has weak consistency guarantees, non resilient...? It will be fast and let us use familiar SQL statements.

Comment: "familiar SQL statements" :) That phrase is the main idea behind your comment - you don't want changes. Progress demands changes.

Comment: @Shehi there's nothing wrong at all with his attempt to stay with something he's familiar with. To begin with, all discoveries and inventions stem from something we're familiar with. Moreover, the scientific method of induction is based on things we're familiar with. Last but not least, there's a cost associated with learning. Jumping around among technologies without proper exposure(I'm talking about time spans of at least 5 years) is not going to help you in the long run.

Comment: This isn't really a "technical answer"

Comment: I know this post & answer are old, but this is just incorrect in regards to **why** MongoDB is fast. Guaranteed consistency has negligible impact on the performance differences, and the lack of ACID principle guarantee in a NoSQL database more so just enables it to be more easily distributed across multiple servers (known as sharding) - that is it makes managing the database easier, but does not make it inherently faster. Likely OP's test wasn't apples to apples between database systems, as unfortunately many don't understand the complex engine SQL Server uses or how to utilize it correctly.

Answer (score 47):

[MongoDB is fast because its web scale!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F-DItXtZs)

Its a fun video and well worth everyone watching, but it does answer your question - that most of the noSQL engines like MongoDB are not robust and not resilient to crashes and other outages.  This security is what they sacrifice to gain speed.

Comment: @JoelFan says someone who has not *yet* seen a crash.  Yank the power cable out off the box you have it running on.  Repeat until you detect corruption, and report back.  One day in real life your hosting will suffer hardware failure, it really does happen.

Answer (score 14):

SQL has to do quite a lot, Mongo just has to drop bits onto disk (almost)

Comment: This was weird, I was going to write more about SQL vs object stores but the question dissapeared?

Comment: I agree. SQL performs complicated operations on data before it gets stored. And while operations performed on Mongo are as necessary as those performed on SQL, it is more faster because of it's simplicity.

Answer (score 13):

As it has been mentioned MongoDB isn't created and shouldn't be used the same as a SQL database. SQL (and other relational databased) store *relational* data, that is that data in table X can be set up to have direct relations to information in table Y. MongoDB doesn't have this ability, and can therefore drop a lot of overhead. Hence why MongoDB is usually used to store lists, not relations.

Add in the fact that it isn't not quite ACID compliant yet (though it has taken large strides since it was first introduced) and that's the bulk of the speed differences.

Here are the differences outlined on the actual site between a full transactional model and their model.

In practice, the non-transactional model of MongoDB has the following implications:

- **No rollbacks**. Your code must function without rollbacks. Check all programmatic conditions before performing the first database
  write operation. Order your write operations such that the most
  important operation occurs last.
- **Explicit locking**. Your code may explicitly lock objects when performing operations. Thus, the application programmer has the
  capability to ensure "serializability" when required. Locking
  functionality will be available in late alpha / early beta release of
  MongoDB.
- **Database check on startup**. Should the database abnormal terminate (rare), a database check procedure will automatically run on startup
  (similar to fschk).

Comment: MongoDb can embed documents or use subdocuments to relate data. It has  storing relational data capabilities very well indeed.

Comment: @Shehi: Embedding and subdocuments won't give you more then tree structure. But MongoDb got (kinda) proper support for relations with manual references (no joins, though).

Comment: That is not what relational means. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation

Answer (score 10):

While the other answers are interesting I would add that one of the reasons MongoDB is "so fast", at least in benchmarks, is the `write concern`.

You can read more about the different write concerns [**here**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) but basically you can define the level of "security" you want when writing data.

The default level used to be **`unacknowledged`**, which means the write operation is just triggered but the driver does not check if it performed successfully. It is faster, but way less reliable.

They changed it about [**one year ago**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/drivers-write-concern/) to **`acknowledged`**. But I guess most of the benchmarks out there still use the 'unacknowledged` mode for better results.

If you want to see the difference in term of performance, you can check [**this article**](http://whyjava.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/how-mongodb-different-write-concern-values-affect-performance-on-a-single-node/) (a bit old but it still gives an idea).

Answer (score 8):

**MongoDB is fast™ because:**

1. Not ACID: Availability is given preference over consistency.
2. Asynchronous insert and update: What it means is, MongoDB doesn't insert the data to DB as soon as insert query is processed but it flushed the data after certain amount of time. Same is true for updates.
3. No Joins overhead: When they say MongoDB is a document database, what they mean is, it is a database that contains data that is self sufficient and all the information is embedded like a real document.

Answer (score 6):

MongoDb is faster because:
1. No transactions;
2. No relations between tables;

If you will try to do exact the same logic on SQL server, for example :
1. Do not use Select with locks ;
2. No relations between tables;
It will not be so big gap in speed between SQL Server and MongoDB. 
**Only one place definitely will be faster , write and update records, because SQL doing insert and update table in the queue and in a transaction, on MondoDB it happens asynchronously.** 
In my projections I could not gain any big differences in speed between SQL SERVER and MongoDB, because business logic was very similar between 2 projects.
Real speed gain on MongoDb you can get on Analytical projects with bid data, or on big content management engines, like news papers, online stores and etc. 
Again no optimization on MongoDB and good optimization on SQL server can make these databases almost equal.

Answer (score 3):

Mongo's not ACID compliant, so it doesn't have to deal with nearly as much "cruft" to make sure that what you try to put into the DB can come back out again later.

If you don't mind losing some functionality and possibly losing data in exchange for speed, then Mongo's good. If you absolutely need to guarantee data integrity and/or have complex join requirements, then avoid Mongo-type systems like the plague.

Comment: Are you sure MongoDB may let you lose data? I don't think so. `Not ACID compliant` doesn't mean it doesn't do anything about keeping data safe, etc. The operations MongoDB does just obey rules under different names.

Comment: @Jack. No, they don't. Yes, MongoDB can lose your data.
Even when you use WriteConcern with the highest level it's still possible to lose the data.

Answer (score 2):

I will also add that another difference is less about speed and more about conceptualization (although I believe that it might help with speed because there is less room for joining issues) is the **document-based storage is very similar to object oriented mindset**.

The document-based might not be perfectly ACID, but I believe MongoDB is easier to get what you want by just getting the whole document rather than messing with all the joins of a SQL DB, risking some bad joins as well.

***Apologies*** to any SQL die-hard fans.

Answer (score 2):

According to MongoDB's website, MongoDB is a document database with the scalability and flexibility that you want and with querying and indexing that you need.

Let's try tho understand what this actually means. So as we know MongoDB is a document-based so it stores data in documents which are field value paired data structures like JSON. So again, it stores data in these documents instead of rows in a table like in traditional relational databases. It's therefore a NoSQL database and not a relational one.

Also, MongoDB has built-in scalability, making it very easy to distribute data across multiple machines as your apps get more and more users and start generating a ton of data. So whatever you do, MongoDB will make it very easy for you to grow.

Another big feature of MongoDB is its great flexibility. There is no need to define a document data schema before filling it with data, meaning that each document can have a different number and type of fields. And we can also change these fields all the time. All this is really in line with some real-world business situations, therefore it can become pretty useful.

MongoDB is also a very performant database system, thanks to features like embedded data models, indexing, sharding, the flexible documents that you know I believe, native duplication  and so much more. And it is a free and open-source database, published under the SSPL license.

In summary, we can say that MongoDB is a great database system to build many types of modern, scalable, and flexible web applications. In fact, Mongo is probably the most used database with node JS.

Now let's know about a bit deeper about these documents considering a blog post example, here is how that exact same data could look like as a row in a relational database like MySQL, or even in an Excel spreadsheet.

[image]

MongoDB uses a data format similar to JSON for data storage called BSON. IT looks basically the same as JSON, but it's typed, meaning that all values will have a data type such as String, Boolean, Date, and Object (such as Teacher Object, Double Object) and more. So what this means is that all MongoDB documents will actually be typed, which is different from JSON.

Now just like JSON, these BSON documents will also have fields, and data is stored in key-value pairs. On the other hand in a relational database, each field is called a column, and database arranges data in table structures while our JSON data is so much more flexible.

Take for example the tags field in the above picture, where we actually have an array, so we have basically multiple values for one field, but in relational databases, that's not really allowed, we cannot have multiple values in one field. So we would actually have to find workarounds for this in a relational database, which could then involve more work and even more overall complication.

Now another extremely important feature in MongoDB is the concept of embedded documents, which is something not present in relational databases. So in our comments field here we have an array that contains three objects, one for each document. So just imagine we have a comments collection which contained a bunch of comment documents, each of them could actually look exactly like this, so with an author and with the comment text, but instead of doing that, we include these comments right into that blog post document, so in other words, we embed the comment documents right into the post document, this is the process of embedding or de-normalizing which is basically to include some related data all into one single document.

In the above example the comments are related to the post and os they are included in the same document which makes a database more performant in some situations because this way it can be easier to read all the data that we need all at once.

Now the opposite of embedding or de-normalizing is normalizing, and that's how the data is always modeled in a relational database. In the above example case it's not possible to embed data in a relational system, solution is to create a whole new table for the comments and then join the tables by referencing the ID field of the comments table.

Two things about BSON documents you need to know:

First, the maximum size for each document is currently 16 MB

Second, each document contains a unique ID, which acts as a primary key of that document, it's automatically generated with the object ID data type each time there is a new document, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Denormalization is one of the jobs of a competent sql database administrator and is what you do to get performance out of sql. The idea that sql databases need to store only normalized data is probably why people complain about the slowness. Normalizing, measuring its performance impact, and then complaining that things are slow is ridiculous and a sign of lack of experience. Competently designed sql schemas will include denormalization - plenty of it - based on the needs of the data access patterns. Whoever said that sql==normalization is a real menace. That’s some serious misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb is a lot faster in inserts and updates, because it does not check the schema and perform foreign key checks, but in reading the data by attributes and searching, its not always faster, specially if you dont have index keys.

More about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8xsuFgCRkU