# Why MongoDB for scrapy data?

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

Why is MongoDB a common advocated choice for scrapy data?
Is there a significant performance hit for using NoSQL versus SQL?

My best guess is that Mongo or any NoSQL allows the flexibility required to store a dynamic irregular/ugly data like web data.  Mongo can evolve with changing requirements of the project/data and departs from rigid schemas required for SQL.

Comment: This is probably a "matter of opinion" question. If you want to use a relational database, you can still do so. Indeed, you could use a relational database in a semi-structured way - columns for data whose structure you know, and JSON columns for unstructured data.

Answer (score 2):

I dug deeper and found several useful references for why to use Mongo, most of which revolve around the flexibility of NoSQL since the data can be unstructured:

Major Differences:

https://medium.com/xplenty-blog/the-sql-vs-nosql-difference-mysql-vs-mongodb-32c9980e67b2

https://db-engines.com/en/system/Microsoft+SQL+Server%3BMongoDB

Performance:

[Any detailed and specific reasons for Why MongoDB is much faster than SQL DBs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244553/any-detailed-and-specific-reasons-for-why-mongodb-is-much-faster-than-sql-dbs)

And although none specifically address why to use NoSQL for Scrapy, it seems to be implied that scraped data is presumed to be unstructured and inherently messy, therefore difficult to implement in a relational data structure.  This wasn't apparent to me initially because my data was structured, but as the project scales, it becomes less so.