# Workflow Website - Back-end Design Advice

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, architecture

**Background:**

I'm beginning to architect/design a new website that will track the workflow of a **large** amount of projects. Each project will have phases assigned to them (*planning, implementation, post-implementation, closing, etc...*). Each of the phases contains different tasks, etc.

Some may ask, "*This sounds very similar to other Workflow Management Software (WMS) that already exists, why not use that?*"

In addition to this site tracking each phase like other WMS tools, it will also need to interact directly with other systems (different domains) and software (APIs/WMIs) directly from the pages. It will allow our admins to maintain Active Directory GPOs, ensure new computers are initialized properly with the correct settings, monitor SQL database fidelity on remote computers and much more. And for those that believe it's important to the question...I'm currently planning to build the website using .NET.

As many of you know, projects and standards change at a rapid pace in the business world. As such, I'm looking to make this site as dynamic and fast-changing as possible in regards to each phase and task. For instance, associates may need to perform an additional task on every project going forward that wasn't previously defined. We will then need to be able to make quick changes to all currently open project entries and all new projects going forward to add the new item to the checklist.

**Question:**

***In everyone's experience, what have you found to be the best way to store large amounts of data that requires new data changes frequently?***

**Initial Thoughts:**

*SQL / Database Storage:*

Pros:

- Easily stores large amounts of data.
- Ability to link the projects/phases/tasks via Primary and Foreign Keys
- Stored Procedures on the back-end would help with manipulating the database and allow for changing of queries without the need to recompile the site. (*Big Plus!*)

Cons:

- New checklist items would result in the need for new columns to be created in each table.
- Complexity of each task could result in joining a large amount of tables.
- Once new columns are created, each Stored Procedure would need modified to ensure the new column is included in its manipulation.

*XML / YAML / Any Markup Language*

Pros:

- Easily manipulated from a "go-forward" changes standpoint.
- Easily can create a new "node" under each Task phase that can update the webpages.

Cons:

- Saving data to files has high volatility (files can be deleted, and no data recover).
- Potential issues with users attempting to accessing files at same time would throw errors (would need to build in 'locks' into the code to read/manipulate a files data).

**Final Comments:**

I'm leaning towards SQL/Database storage, but don't see changes to the design/framework being a quick feat. If there are any methods of data storage that I'm leaving out that could be a potential better fit to the solution, please let me know.

Thanks Everyone.

Comment: I think SQL Server would be a good fit for you. It has a nice gui and many different tools with it. As for upgrading  it is as easy as backing up and restoring your DB on the newest version. I hve used a few different systems like Oracle, Postrgres, Teradata, and others; so far SQL Server us my favorite easy to navigate and tons of documentation on the internet.

Comment: @WesPalmer Thanks Wes. I've been leaning that way as well. It doesn't look there will be any easy solution to the problem fast changing environment. Every route looks to require a backend and front end change when an addition is needed.

Answer (score 2):

More details are needed to recommend you some specific storage. But from your description a project looks like a document with many attributes and child items like this:

```
{
 "id": 43233,
 "name": "MyProject",
 "created": "02/01/2017",
 "owner": {
 "id": 32132,
 "name": "John Smith"
}
"tasks": [
{
  "id": 43243,
  "name": "Task1",
  "priority": "high",
  "status": "new"
 },
 {
  "id": 43253,
  "name": "Task2",
   "priority": "low",
   "status": "done"
 }
]}
```

A document database can be more suitable for you if your app doesn't need to make a lot requests across projects and works with one project mostly. Document databases like MongoDB, CouchDB, Azure Document DB and so on have less restriction on data schema and as a rule are scaled out much better than SQL database.

So, you can easier change project object schema adding new attributes. Retrieving project object will be also much easier - you don't need to do a lot of SQL joins in order to "construct" project.

About performance: it depends on how you are going to use DB. For above example you will have:

1. To create project – one insert into document db vs 4 inserts (project, owner, 2 tasks) into SQL
2. To get project – one read vs one pretty complex select with joins. The more complex project object you have the more select statement will be.
3. But if you need to get app projects or tasks filtered by some criteria SQL will be of cause more convenient and apparently has better performance.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, the hierarchy you specified above looks like what I envision the design to be. I have not looked at document databases before. After a quick search it looks promising, but in your experience, how are the speed of queries against the document database vs. relational DBs?

Comment: I added in the answer some general performance comparison SQL db vs document. More details I think you can get for instance here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186707/why-is-mongodb-so-fast

Comment: After doing a little more research, document database may not be the correct way to go. From my reading it says that it can be hard to gather reporting off of a document database. Are there any tools that you've used to help with, say MongoDB, that gives good reporting?

Comment: You came up to the 3 point in my answer. I think something usefull about Mongo Analitics you can find https://slamdata.com/guides/the-definitive-guide-to-mongodb-analytics/